# Kotlin. Как преобразовать числа с 1 до 9 в строку, в виде "01"-"09". Т.е. чтобы слева добавлялся 0?

Tags: android, строки, kotlin, форматирование

Как преобразовать числа с 1 до 9 в строку, в виде "01"-"09", то есть чтобы слева добавлялся 0?

```
fun main() {
   var month:Int = 1
   println(month.toString())
}  
// выводит: 1, а надо: 01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`string.Format(Any?)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html), где `Any` — любой nullable-тип (в том числе и `int`), а `string` — [форматная строка](https://www.fandroid.info/6-osnovy-kotlin-osnovy-tekstovogo-vvoda-vyvoda/2/) (здесь — `%02d`, т.е. число, использующее как минимум 2 цифры, а недостающие заполняет слева нулями).

Ещё статья на тему форматирования: [тут](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1412-formatiruem-vihvod-chisel-v-java)

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var month:Int = 1
    print("%02d".format(month))
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, это сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте возможности String.format("")

```
fun main() {
   var month:Int = 1  
   println(String.format("%02d",month))
}
// выводит 01
```

Вот неплохая статья на эту тему http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/formatirovanie-chisel-i-texta-v-java/

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!

Comment: Рекомендую также закрывать в таких случаях вопрос, выбрав один из наиболее полных ответов как верный (нажать на галочку слева)

Comment: Спасибо, поставил галочку над Вашим ответом! Я новичок на stackoverflow, не знал, что так надо делать!